# Сохранение файла из рабочего пространства Matlab

Tags: matlab

Я пытаюсь сохранить файл из рабочего пространства Матлаб с помощью следующей команды:

save 'mydat.dat' 'time', где

'time' - последовательность заданных чисел

Файл сохраняется, но некорректно:

MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Oct 28 22:15:03 2020                                                 IM   ^   xњ]ЗM
@P†бЈ.]%IH’ьнГЭЊЃЃ™EY’Ў%єЬwд«·зњXD[`УшОзПmЮ—’mYзРЮ»ьwNОoгPЁ1ВSМ°А+¬±Б;мqАС<уєВ

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Команда save предназначена для сохранения файлов в формате .mat - MATLAB® formatted binary file (MAT-file). Чтобы прочитать этот файл, используйте `load('mydat.mat')`